# What would the function definition look like if it uses another function inside - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have found this code on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38774358/1954132) :

```
function dothings(things, ondone){
    function go(i){
        if (i >= things.length) {
            ondone();
        } else {
            dothing(things[i], function(result){
                return go(i+1);
            });
        }
    }
    go(0);
}
```

I couldn't figure out how I should define `dothing` function. Should it be like this :

```
function dothing(elem)
{
   //do things with elem
}
```

Or should I somehow indicate the `function(result)`, if yes how should I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dothing` is an asynchronous function here.

In asynchronous function signature, a callback is one of the params.

Also in order to return a value from a async function, the callback needs to be called with the value to be returned.
A return statement does not make sense in async function.

The definition can look like:

```
function dothing(elem, callback){
     // Your logic to process elem
     // var result = some_custom_logic(elem);
     callback(result);
}
```

Comment: And I don't need to define the functionality of `callback` in somewhere else right? Because it's being defined inside `dothings`?

Comment: Yes, it is true. The definition of callback method is being passed when dothing is invoked inside the `dothings`.

Comment: One more question : Should `result` essentially be meaningful? I'm just modifying an external array in my actual code.

Comment: It is not a requirement to pass a result. I just showed a way to pass result if there is a need.

Answer (score 1):

do it like this,

```
function dothing(elem, cb)
{
   //do things with elem
   // return the result
   cb(...somedata)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define dothing like this

```
function dothing(elem, callback){
    //result =  do stuff with elem
    callback(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit overcomplicated, because it calls the function over and over again and does not work for the elements of `things` and and in the reverse order for calling `ondone` function.

```js
function dothings(things, ondone) {
    function go(i) {
        if (i < things.length) {
            console.log(i, things[i]);
            go(i + 1);
            ondone(i);
        }
    }

    go(0);
}

dothings([1, 2, 3, 4], function (v) { console.log(v, 'done'); })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```